# Modify AST in plugin headless mode

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I have created a plugin in eclipse with support of cdt api's, the plugin does some code refactoring, and it works fine, I want to extend this plugin to run in headless mode, I created an entry point that implements IApplication and it works fine to enter the start method, the problem comes in applying code changes, when I try to modify the code

```
  Change c = rewriter.rewriteAST();
        try {
            c.perform(new NullProgressMonitor());
        } catch (CoreException e) {
            logger.error("Faild to persist changes",e);
        }
```

it gives me exception says `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workbench has not been created yet.`
but it does code refactor, my question does the Change.perform is apart of the UI module and how to avoid this exception? 
Full stack trace link:   https://pastebin.com/iiKzvisQ

Comment: Also there is something weird in the exception trace:
!MESSAGE Plug-in org.eclipse.cdt.ui was unable to load class org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.editor.CDocumentSetupParticipant.
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.cdt.ui (49).

Comment: @HighCommander4 any ideas?